# Selenium C# - Assert a specific tag within a recurring div

Tags: c#, selenium

C#  with selenium webdriver here! (very new to both, VbScript/QTP background)

On this webpage there's a recurring `DIV`. I want to look inside each instance of it, verify some content inside it/assert every instance of it. Specifically, I want to assert that: the text inside the first instance of each div (div's classname=`span7`) is wrapped in a `<b> ... </b>` tag. In other words, I need to assert that all the text in that `DIV` is bold.

The catch: There are two `span7`s, the first (I've called it "cat1") needs to be `<b>bold</b>`. The second span7, I can safely ignore. FYI, there are about ten occurrences of this div class ("types") all next to each other.

```
<div class="types">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span3 h4">Cat1</div>
      <div class="span7">
         <b>THIS TEXT SHOULD BE BOLD</b>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span3 h4">Cat2</div>
      <div class="span7">
         This text doesnt need to be bold
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would code it like this (this is a mixture of the C# I know + what I want C# to help me do)

```
if (theparentof  Driver.FindElements(By.Classname("span7") = "Cat2" 
then ignore
else Assert.Istrue( Driver.FindElements(By.Classname("span7")).Text contains <b>
```

Comment: You want someone to do it for you? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @cocoa apologies, please see my edit above re. how I am trying to code the problem thus far. I concede that cat2 may not be the parent of the div I need although that's how I wrote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would tackle this is to loop through the `DIV` elements that have class `types` (CSS selector `div.types`). For each of those `DIV`s, look for the first `DIV` with class `span7` (CSS selector `div.span7`) and then look for a `B` tag inside. If that `B` tag doesn't exist, then the test fails.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> types = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.types"));
foreach (IWebElement type in types)
{
    Assert.Istrue(type.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.span7")).FindElements(By.TagName("b")).Count > 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff, for edits and this suggestion, which makes sense to me, I just have 2 questions to help me understand.
1) In your " foreach ... Where are you declaring 'type' beforehand ? I can only see that CssSelector "div.types" and that is a string, which doesn't seem to be it. What is type? And why does it not need to be defined?

2) Does this deal with the issue of my needing to assert that the b tag exists only in 1 div, and being able to ignore the 2nd div (I can't have the test fail if it doesn't find b tag in the 2nd div because as I said there are multiple occurrences on this page?

Comment: `type` is defined in the `foreach` loop inside the parens... it's `IWebElement`. You can read more about the `foreach` syntax to see how it works and how the variable is declared. Yes, it only looks for the `B` tag under a single span. You should try the code and make sure it works for you. Let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off grabbing exactly the elements you want to test. In this case, you can either go with Selenium's provided `By` alternatives, or do it yourself using the general `By.CssSelector` or `By.XPath`.

Or you could fix the HTML so that all elements that need to be identified in tests have unique id attributes. *This is definitely the best option.*

**Option 1: Use linq and By.ClassName**:
The Single() will throw an exception if there is more than one matching element.

```
var elementToTest = Driver.FindElements(
    By.ClassName("row").SelectMany(e =>
        e.FindElements(By.ClassName("span7"))).Single();
```

**Option 2: Use CssSelector**:
Again the Single() will throw an exception if there is more than one matching element.

```
var elementToTest = Driver.FindElements(
    By.CssSelector(".row > .span7")).Single();
```

**Option 3: Use XPath**:
Again the Single() will throw an exception if there is more than one matching element.

```
var elementToTest = Driver.FindElements(
    By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'row')]/div[contains(@class, 'span7')]"))
    .Single();
```

But really, you should change the HTML. Put id attributes on everything that you need to test.